# Not receiving Post request response message in mobile in react native?

Tags: react-native

[image]

Hi guys,
        I made a Http post request in react native  i received success message on debugger by inspect but showing error on my Alert.  My problem i received status true in debugger but receiving error alert in front.Please help me where i made a mistake.I don't know why it comes under error alert.I think its correct.

```
  CallSignIn()
  {
  try 
     {
    let response = fetch('post url will be here', 
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: 
        {
        'x-api-key':   '1k1gdyaa7bdy', // this is example key but original token key have to pass
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
              email: this.state.email,
              password: this.state.password,
       })
       });
        if (response.status > 200 && response.status < 300) 
        {
          this.setState({showProgress: false})
          let res=response.status;
          Alert.alert(res);
        }
        else
        {
        let error;
        Alert.alert("Error :",error);
        this.setState({showProgress: false})
        }
        } catch(e) 
        {
        Alert.alert("Error:",error);
        this.setState({showProgress: false})
  }
}
onSignInPress() 
{
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    if (this.isValid()) 
    {
     this.setState({showProgress: true})
     NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done((isConnected) => 
        {
        if ( isConnected )
        {
          this.CallSignIn();
        }
        else
        {
          Alert.alert("Internet is Offline")
        }
        });
       }
    }
```

Comment: Have you ever, like ever, looked at the docs on **fetch**? It returns a promise.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve], providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.